# Use of という in a sentence

Tags: quotes, japanese-to-english

Hope someone can help me. I'm struggling with the exact usage of という in this sentence:

> 会う約束をした友達から乗っている電車が止まっている**という**メールが来た。

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> 会う約束をした友達から乗っている電車が止まっている**という**メールが来た。

This という means "saying that" and is describing the contents of the メール.

The main part of the sentence is this:

> 会う約束をした友達からメールが来た。

Xというメール is "an e-mail which says X".

Answer (score 1):

という is used to indicate the object or thing you are talking about. Or want to convey something about which you do not know on depth.
For example : 学校という言葉を習いました。(I learnt a word as "school")