# what does mean in these following phrases the grammar rule 「という」

Tags: grammar

on my book there are these sentences that I didn't understand

> - 新聞に、来月フランスの大統領が来日する**という**記事が出ている。
> - １９９３年に山形県で最高気温が４０度を超えた**という**記録がある。
> - 日本には、月でうさぎがもちをついている**という**古くからの言い伝えがあります。
> - １９７３年にトイレットペーパーがなくなる**という**うわさが日本中に流れて、多くの人々がスーパーに殺到した。

Comment: Provide us with your translation attempt so that we can assist you in getting this question answered. Thank you and welcome to Japanese Stack Exchange!

Comment: While working on your translations, recall that the いう in という is the verb 言う meaning "to say," and it can be interpreted literally (i.e., you can use the verb "say" in the English translation) in all of these cases.

Comment: related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68976/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expresses apposition.

> 日本には、月でうさぎがもちをついているという古くからの言い伝えがあります。
>   In japan, there is an old tradition that rabbits are making mochi on the moon.